# How would "powered by" be translated?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

It's very usual to find this in websites or softwares, like for example, when a website uses a software or functionality from another company as part of its functionality, somewhere in the website there's a "powered by <<sub><sub><sub><sub>.</sub></sub></sub></sub>company or software name>".

What would be the equivalent in Portuguese?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that it is common to some companies to use the term:

> Fornecido por

Joomla uses this translation for their templates:

- [Live example](http://www.ambientelivre.com.br/tutoriais-pentaho-bi/retirando-a-mensagem-do-rodape-do-jpivot-no-pentaho-4-ce-.html) (see the footnote)
- And a [discussion](http://forum.joomlapt.com/j15-modelos/como-tirar-o-fornecido-pelo-joomla-do-milkyway-t5873.html) in their forum

Wordpress seems to have agreed with this term as well:

- [Source](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/3.7.x/gl/default?filters%5Bstatus%5D=either&filters%5Boriginal_id%5D=73139&filters%5Btranslation_id%5D=3052885)

When trying to translate the "powered by" alone you usually get some weird suggestions, but when translating the term within a context some online translators brings lots of examples using the same term. Example:

- [Linguee - Translation for "Powered by Google"](http://www.linguee.com.br/ingles-portugues/traducao/powered+by+google.html)

Comment: Perhaps it's just my perception, but _fornecido por_ seems a _neutral_ way to describe the company who provided something (a hosting service, the searching engine used in a website, etc.) and _powered by_ seems to me more like a positive way of saying the same thing. Like if the website is _proud_ that company XXX is offering it's hosting service or providing the search engine used. Anyone agree?

Comment: I agree, but I'm Brazilian and I'm not sure how natives speakers of English feels about that. It'd be nice to hear an opinion from them.

Comment: What better than use English SE to ask native speakers to clarify that doubt? Well, I asked [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274746/has-the-expression-powered-by-as-used-in-website-or-softwares-a-positive-con), let's wait and hear from them!

Comment: This answer is not accurate at all. fornecido means supplied and has zero to do with powered by. How can it have gotten so many upvotes?

Comment: @Lambie I've cited a few real life examples that "fornecido por" is being used as an appropriate translation for "powered by". Also gmauch asked how "powered by" sounds to native ears and accordingly to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/274753/44804) just by specifying a brand that is a giant of its kind it already sounds as an enhancement to your product as if you're advertising and promoting it. Finally, I researched again and still can't think a better term for that, nor can see a better answer here at this topic, so, I really believe that this is the best answer so far.

Comment: @gmauch notifying you just in case you want to add something to this discussion

Comment: Just saying something is right does not make it so. fornecer means to supply in Portuguese, a fornecedor is  supplier. My conclusion is simply there seems to be a gap in knoweledge of Portuguese. You are using automatic translation programs whereas one has to actually speak the languages...

Comment: @Lambie I'm a Portuguese (PT_BR) native speaker and can't think of a term other than "fornecido por" that is used in websites and software when "powered by" would be used. I also agree that it does sound a little more neutral. In short "fornecido por" is used when someone would write "powered by" in a website, but it's meaning is not exactly the same. The other answers in this Q seem to better convey the meaning of "powered by" (the positive tone), but would seem rather strange to my ears (eyes) in a website.

Comment: @gmauch I am not going to argue about it. There are hits for tecnologiía movida por IA, for example. A translation to be sure, but accurate.

Answer (score 9):

Even though **fornecido por** has been used in place of **powered by** already I’d like to present some alternatives for you consideration. Namely:

> Assistido por
>
> Habilitado por
>
> Suportado por
>
> Ajudado por

Here are my reasons. Suppose you have *webpage X* which uses some *functionality Z supplied by firm Z*, but *functionality Z* does not do all the work, it only helps *webpage X* to work seamlessly; or we might say *functionality Z* enables *webpage X*. So any of the alternatives above sort of conveys that idea, and has a more upbeat feel to it than *fornecido por*. [Habilitar](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/habilitar), *tornar hábil ou apto a, prover (outrem) do preciso (para um fim)* corresponds more closely to *enable*. It might take some getting used to, because it also has a legal meaning which is not relevant here. Otherwise it’s probably my favourite, followed by [*assistido por*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/assistir).

The literal translation of *powered by* is of course *movido por, motorizado por*. As used in the present context I suppose all *powered by* means is precisely *enabled by*, *made to work by.* which is not far from the phrases I suggested.

Answer (score 3):

In the following phrases, **"powered"** is used with a noun to inform what kind of energy provides power to a certain equipment or machinery.

- **nuclear-powered**
- **solar-powered**
- **battery-powered**

With the advent of the computer, it began to be used to **refer to a firm or corporation that provides the hardware** (hard-disk, processor, motherboard).

In such cases, **"powered by XXX"** could be translated as **"energizado por"** or, simply, **"funciona com hardware da..."**

In ptBR ["hardware"](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=with+the+advent+of&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Akf7Vc-iBsaB8QfP-ZToCQ&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=hardware+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o+de%2C+dicion%C3%A1rio) is a loan-word and is described in most dictionaries as "conjunto de unidades físicas que compõem um computador ou seus periféricos."

Comment: energizado soa meio calco p'ra mim....

Answer (score 0):

This is not a neutral term. It is not merely informative, and is usually used as a marketing or branding phrase, to communicate that the product allows you to do great things.

So I would use **Empoderado por**, as it is directly correlated with “power”.

It preserves the original meaning of the term – which refers to improved capacity and drivenness – but also addresses the connotation of pride that it carries today.

“Empoderado” is also a word that is quite common in today's Brazilian Portuguese parlance.

Comment: empoderar is empowered, not the same thing at all. People are empowered by this or that and websites are powered by this or that tech.

Comment: Yes, but a direct translation of “powered by” in the context of a website does not make any sense either. Language is a dynamic thing, there's absolutely no need to be literal in this case.

Comment: Of course it does. It's used all the time for programs and platforms and software, which is what the OP wanted. Also, you mistranslated powered by as empoderado which is empowered in English. And I found two examples in Portuguese.

Comment: Powered by IBM software, the new personalized feedback
capabilities in the BodyMedia FIT body monitoring system now provide users
with their own fitness coach. https://www.bloomberg.com/press-releases/2012-01-11/bodymedia-selects-ibm-software-to-personalize-weight-loss-advice

Comment: I was not referring to the use of the term in English. I agree with you on that. I was talking about the portuguese translation for that term. There's no consensus about it, as we can see in this very thread.

Comment: I couldn't find the examples mentioned.

Comment: The Portuguese has zero to do with empoderar which is empower.  I won't bother to repeat this again.

Comment: Empoderar = capacitar, habilitar, possibilitar...  How does this have “zero to do” with the use of the term “Powered by” in the context of a website or app? That's exactly what it means *in this specific context*. But at least we agree on one thing: I will also rest my case.

Comment: Marcio: **Você colocou o verbo empoderar** em português como tradução do **verbo power** em inglês. Isso é um error de tradução. Procura num bom dicionário.

Comment: Collins dictionary: to power 1. (electricity and electronics) alimentar
2. (engine, machine) acionar
3. (car, plane) propulsionar

Answer (score 0):

solar-powered is movido por energia solar

Cambridge Dictionary

Tambem se ve: movido a energia nuclear e movido por bateria ou movido a bateria

Então, eu diria:

**movido por [x]**

Por exemplo:

> 4 – Anúncios  Agora observa o seguinte. **Esse site é movido por
> anúncios, é assim que ele monetiza para te entregar de graça esse tipo
> de serviço.**

[movido por](https://fiqueisemcracha.com.br/como-converter-videos-do-youtube-para-o-instagram-pelo-celular/)

E isso:

> BMW está a desenvolver **um carro movido a hidrogénio**. Veja o
> protótipo!

BMW is developing a **hydrogen-powered car**. See the prototype!
[movido a hidrogénio](https://pplware.sapo.pt/motores/bmw-desenvolver-carro-hidrogenio-prototipo/)

E esse:

> Prepare-se para descobrir uma forma revolucionária de interagir com
> seus jogadores e dar vida a suas partidas de RPG, pois a empresa
> multicultural fundada por brasileiros Fantastic Art Studios anuncia
> hoje a data da campanha de Kickstarter de **seu novo software movido
> por Inteligência Artificial, o Black Box Map Maker**.
> [software movido por IA](https://www.gamersegames.com.br/2021/10/26/criador-de-mapas-animados-em-3d-black-box-map-maker-chega-em-breve-ao-kickstarter/)

Comment: This seems good for those cases in which there's actual movement involved. A website, an app or a software does not move, so it does not make any sense to say “Site X é movido por Y”.

Comment: powered means moved by, made to work by. It has nothing to do with empower and empowerment which is a social/sociology term for helping people who didn't have help before. Empowering impoverished communities to stand on their own. That is empoderar.

Comment: Yes, in English this division is obvious, but when you try to translate “Powered by” into Portuguese, the lines get a little more blurred, specifically when the term is used in contexts where the original meaning doesn’t directly apply: websites, apps and software. If the question wasn't specifically about that, I would 100% agree.

Comment: O problema principal aqui é uma falta de domínio da língua inglesa e portuguesa em termos de tradução nesse contexto.

Comment: Uma simples busca pela web revela diversas traduções desse termo: desenvolvido por, ativado por, alimentado por, entre outros descritos aqui no tópico. Obviamente, não há um consenso sobre a tradução, tampouco uma palavra final sobre o assunto. Afirmar o contrário é um uso limitante da linguagem que não leva em consideração o contexto.

Comment: @MarcioDuarte Sim, to power pode ser várias coisas, mas não empoderar como na sua resposta.